# How to get the closing price of apple stock for the last Friday for each month?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I want to get closing price of apple stock for the last Friday for each month. How can i do it ?  Thx

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
apple=yf.Ticker("AAPL")
apple=apple.history(period="5y")
```

Comment: what is your price data looks like ?

Comment: i have updated the code. Just like the normal dataframe. THX

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of doing it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

apple=yf.Ticker("AAPL")
apple=apple.history(period="5y")

apple['weekday'] = apple.index.weekday
apple['month_year'] = apple.index.to_period('M')
apple['date'] = apple.index

friday_groupy = apple[apple['weekday'] == 4].groupby(['month_year'])
apple.loc[friday_groupy['date'].idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1):

An example solution:

```
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf
import calendar

# create dataframe
df = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
df = df.history(period="5y")

df.head()

# define helper function for retrieving last fridays for a given year
def last_fridays(year):
    result = []
    for month in range(1, 13):
        last_friday = max(week[calendar.FRIDAY] for week in calendar.monthcalendar(year, month))
        result.append('{:4d}-{:02d}-{:02d}'.format(year, month, last_friday))
    return result

last_fridays = [frd for y in pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).year for frd in last_fridays(y)]

# filter dataframe
df.loc[df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').isin(last_fridays)]
```